# The name 'str' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, syntax

I have declared a class variable in here

```
void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        Stream responseStream = e.Result;
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();


        string[] split1 = Regex.Split(response, "},{");
        List<string> pri1 = new List<string>(split1);
        pri1.RemoveAt(0);
        string last = pri1[pri1.Count() - 1];
        pri1.Remove(last);

    }
}
```

and I want to use the class variable `str` in this method

```
void AddPrimaryMarkerGraphics(object sender, getPrimaryListCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    List<PrimaryClass> primaryList = new List<PrimaryClass>(e.Result);
    PrimaryClass sc = new PrimaryClass();
    for (int a = 0; a <= e.Result.Count - 1; a++)
    {
        string schname = e.Result.ElementAt(a).PrimarySchool;
        string tophonour = e.Result.ElementAt(a).TopHonour;
        string cca = e.Result.ElementAt(a).Cca;
        string topstudent = e.Result.ElementAt(a).TopStudent;
        string topaggregate = e.Result.ElementAt(a).TopAggregate;
        string topimage = e.Result.ElementAt(a).TopImage;

        foreach (string item in str)
        {
            string abc = "[{" + item + "}]";
            byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(abc);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buf);

            JsonArray users = (JsonArray)JsonArray.Load(ms);

            var members = from member in users
                          //where member["SEARCHVAL"]
                          select member;

            foreach (JsonObject member in members)
            {
                string schname = member["SEARCHVAL"];
                string axisX = member["X"];
                string axisY = member["Y"];
                // Do something...
                string jsonCoordinateString = "{'Coordinates':[{'X':" + axisX + ",'Y':" + axisY + "}]}";
                CustomCoordinateList coordinateList = DeserializeJson<CustomCoordinateList>(jsonCoordinateString);

                GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["MyGraphicsLayer_Primary"] as GraphicsLayer;

                for (int i = 0; i < coordinateList.Coordinates.Count; i++)
                {
                    Graphic graphic = new Graphic()
                    {
                        Geometry = new MapPoint(coordinateList.Coordinates[i].X, coordinateList.Coordinates[i].Y),
                        Symbol = i > 0 ? PrimarySchoolMarkerSymbol : PrimarySchoolMarkerSymbol

                    };
                    graphic.Attributes.Add("PrimarySchool", schname);
                    graphic.Attributes.Add("xcoord", axisX);
                    graphic.Attributes.Add("ycoord", axisY);
                    graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's where the error shows.

Comment: You need to show more of your code Im afraid, as its obviously convinced str is out of context.

Comment: what is the data type of pri1? Can you post complete code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost certainly declared the variable in a method (i.e. as a *local* variable), instead of directly in the class itself (as an *instance* variable). For example:

```
// Wrong
class Bad
{
    void Method1()
    {
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
    }

    void Method2()
    {
        foreach (string item in str)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

// Right
class Good
{
    private List<string> str = new List<string>();

    void Method1()
    {
        str = CreateSomeOtherList();
    }

    void Method2()
    {
        foreach (string item in str)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

As a side-note: if you're very new to C#, I would *strongly* recommend that you stop working on Silverlight temporarily, and write some console apps just to get you going, and to teach you the basics. That way you can focus on C# as a language and the core framework types (text, numbers, collections, I/O for example) and then start coding GUIs later. GUI programming often involves learning a lot more things (threading, XAML, binding etc) and trying to learn everything in one go just makes things harder.

Comment: i dun hav a choice it has been assigned to me and there's much time left

Comment: @GJJ: What do you mean by "it has been assigned to me"? You don't have any choice in how you learn? Learning one step at a time will get you to your goal faster.

Comment: @Jon its an assignment, i cant choose the project to take

Comment: @GJJ: But you can choose how to learn what you need to complete the assignment. If you learn via small console apps, you'll be able to concentrate on learning one thing at a time, and then build up all that knowledge into the final assignment.

Comment: @Jon thanks for the advice i'll keep that in mind for my next big project, but for now it's too late for this project

Comment: @GJJ: So you keep saying - but you're going to run into problem after problem, and be unsure where the issue lies. If it's really too late to learn in a step-by-step way, I think it's probably too late for you to get the project done satisfactorily at all.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because str is not declared in the other variable. It's sscopong problem. Can you pass str as an input to the other function?